# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeContent

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, apache-camel

I encountered this error on the console on my eclipse-workspace while setting up my pom.xml on my spring boot app. I'm currently using spring-boot version 2.5.6

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter

And the code below are the dependencies that i have added.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org-apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-swagger-java-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${camel.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>java.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.200</version>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

I just don't know if some of my dependencies if there are incompatibilities.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Edit:
Additional Logs

```
Description

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

org.apache.camel.impl.engine.SimpleCamelContext.createTypeConverter(SimpleCamelContext.java:138)

referring to this code

135: protected TypeConverter createTypeConverter(){
136:    return new DefaultTypeConverter(
137:        getCamelContextReference(), getPackageScanClassResolver(), getInjector(),
138:        isLoadTypeConverter());



The following method did not exist:

org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter. <init>(Lorg/apache/camel/CamelContext;Lorg/apache/camel/spi/PackageScanClassResolver;Lorg/apache/camel/spi/Injector:V

The method’s class, org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter, is available from the following locations: 

jar:file:/apache/camel/camel-base/3.0.0-M4/camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar!/org/apache/camel/impl/converter/DefaultTypeConverter.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter: camel/camel-base/3.0.0-M4/camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar
org.apache.camel.impl.concerter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry file: camel/camel-base/3.0.0-M4/camel-base-3.0.0-M4.jar
org.apache.camel.support.service.ServiceSupport: file:/camel/camel-api/3.13.0/camel-api-3.13.0.jar
org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService: file:/camel/camel-api/3.13.0/camel-api-3.13.0.jar
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error message? It should have provided more information about the code that tried to call `DefaultTypeConverter` and the locations on the classpath from which `DefaultTypeConverter` is available.

Comment: Hello, i already added the additional logs

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different version of Camel's jars. You have some at version `3.13.0` and others at `3.0.0-M4` and they are not compatible with each other.

You haven't shared all of your `pom.xml` so I can't tell for certain, but I would guess that the `camel.version` property is set to `3.0.0.M4` which is not aligned with your dependency on the Camel starter where the version is `3.13.0`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You should update your pom so that a consistent version is used for all of Camel's modules. You can check their versions by running `mvn dependency:list` on the command line.